# How to disable ad from Gitlens and access functionality?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I've been a happy user of Gitlens for some time. But suddenly the activity button does not activate the usual functionality, instead it activates an ad.

How can I get rid of this add and restore the functionality?

[image]